# Scroll to top a div if already was called slideToggle function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want that buttons `Demarer` and `Stop` to be scrolled up when div `controls-popup` is toggled (and not have a fixed position). Have you an idea about that ?
I have this code :

```js
$(".hide-controls").click(function() {
  $(".controls-popup").slideToggle(1000);
  $(".actions-popup").scrollTop();
});
```

```css
.controls-popup {
  position: absolute;
  left: 572px;
  top: 10%;
  width: 400px;
}

.controls-popup-header {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #fff;
  border-left: 10px solid #747474;
}

.controls-popup-body {
  background-color: #4C4C4C;
  padding: 15px 5px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.controls-popup-body span {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
}

.controls-popup-body .form-label {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.actions-popup {
  position: absolute;
  left: 572px;
  top: 40%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="controls-popup">
  <div class="controls-popup-header">
    Test
  </div>
  <div class="controls-popup-body">
    <span>Test span</span>
    <p></p>
    <span class="form-label">Label : </span>
    <p></p>
    <span class="form-label">Label 2 : </span>
  </div>
  <div class="color-picker" id="my-color-picker-1"></div>
</div>
<div class="actions-popup">
  <button class="start">Demarer</button>
  <button class="stop">Stop</button>
</div>
<a class="hide-controls" href="#">
  <span class="top-arrow">&#8593;</span> Masquer les contrôles
</a>
```

The result :

[image]

After toggle :

[image]

Comment: @mplungjan I added .css also

Comment: Check my updated solution please. It's now as the way you want. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You could try animate:

```js
$(".hide-controls").click(function() {
  if ($(".controls-popup").is(':visible')) {
    $(".controls-popup").slideToggle(1000);
    $(".actions-popup").fadeIn()
      .css({
        top: '40%',
        position: 'absolute'
      })
      .animate({
        top: '10%'
      }, 1000, function() {
        //callback
      });
  } else {
    $(".controls-popup").slideToggle(1000);
    $(".actions-popup").fadeIn()
      .css({
        top: '10%',
        position: 'absolute'
      })
      .animate({
        top: '40%'
      }, 1000, function() {
        //callback
      });
  }
});
```

```css
.controls-popup {
  position: absolute;
  left: 572px;
  top: 10%;
  width: 400px;
}

.controls-popup-header {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #fff;
  border-left: 10px solid #747474;
}

.controls-popup-body {
  background-color: #4C4C4C;
  padding: 15px 5px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.controls-popup-body span {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
}

.controls-popup-body .form-label {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.actions-popup {
  position: absolute;
  left: 572px;
  top: 40%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="controls-popup">
  <div class="controls-popup-header">
    Test
  </div>
  <div class="controls-popup-body">
    <span>Test span</span>
    <p></p>
    <span class="form-label">Label : </span>
    <p></p>
    <span class="form-label">Label 2 : </span>
  </div>
  <div class="color-picker" id="my-color-picker-1"></div>
</div>
<div class="actions-popup">
  <button class="start">Demarer</button>
  <button class="stop">Stop</button>
</div>
<a class="hide-controls" href="#">
  <span class="top-arrow">&#8593;</span> Masquer les contrôles
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is contain the elements in an absolutely positioned container, and then position them relatively inside this container. You'll be able to position the box and the buttons relative to each other inside the absolutely positioned container.

Here's what the code might look like.

```js
$('.hide-controls').click(() => {
    $('.controls-popup').slideToggle(1000);
});
```

```css
.container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    height: 90%;
    left: 20%;
}
.controls-popup {
    position: relative;
    width: 40%;
}
.controls-popup-header {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #fff;
    border-left: 10px solid #747474;
}
.controls-popup-body {
    background-color: #4C4C4C;
    padding: 15px 5px;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
.controls-popup-body span {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff;
}
.controls-popup-body .form-label {
    font-size: 16px;
}
.actions-popup {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="controls-popup">
        <div class="controls-popup-header">Test</div>
        <div class="controls-popup-body">
            <span>Test span</span>
            <p></p>
            <span class="form-label">Label : </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actions-popup">
        <button class="start">Demarer</button>
        <button class="stop">Stop</button>
    </div>
</div>
<a class="hide-controls" href="#">Hide</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code:

```
$('.hide-controls').click(() => {
    $('.controls-popup').slideToggle(1000);
    if($('.actions-popup').hasClass('margin-top')) {
      $('.actions-popup').removeClass('margin-top')
    } else {
      $('.actions-popup').addClass('margin-top')
    }
});
```

```
<div class="link">
    <a class="hide-controls" href="#">
        <span class="top-arrow">&#8593;</span> Masquer les contrôles
    </a>
</div>

<div class="controls-popup">
  <div class="controls-popup-header">
    Test
  </div>
  <div class="controls-popup-body">
    <span>Test span</span>
    <p></p>
    <span class="form-label">Label : </span>
    <p></p>
    <span class="form-label">Label 2 : </span>
  </div>
  <div class="color-picker" id="my-color-picker-1"></div>
</div>

<div class="actions-popup">
  <button class="start">Demarer</button>
  <button class="stop">Stop</button>
</div>
```

```
.link, .actions-popup {
    position: relative;
    left: 20%;
}

.actions-popup > button {
    margin-top: 1%
}

.controls-popup {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    left: 20%;
}
.controls-popup {
    position: relative;
    width: 40%;
}
.controls-popup-header {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #fff;
    border-left: 10px solid #747474;
}
.controls-popup-body {
    background-color: #4C4C4C;
    padding: 15px 5px;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
.controls-popup-body span {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff;
}
.controls-popup-body .form-label {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Visit to see working solution on live: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/rashedrahat/pen/PoWjeVM)

Happy coding :)

Comment: Not working as expected, I want buttons : Demarer and Stop to be below the controls-popup

Comment: Did you check on live? If yes then can you please visit the link `codepen` solution again? I have updated just now. Its as expected now.

Comment: Check my solution again please. I did as the way you want :)

Comment: thank you for the response, but how I can have a padding top 2% for actions-popup ? I tried but is not working very well, I need somehow remove padding when slideToggle()

Comment: I tried to remove the .css : setTimeout(function(){
                    $(".actions-popup").css("margin-top", "0");
                }, 100);

Comment: Updated my answer. Also have a look on live. `margin-top: 1%` change as per your need :)

Comment: yes but I want to have margin-top: 0 when is slideToggle hidden, and again margin-top: 1% when is not hidden

Comment: Updated the answer. Check now. Is this ok?

Comment: Did you check? Let me know.